# Asynchronous task makes program hang

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a task that needs to call an http request to server and I do it like this:

```cs
public static async Task<BoundingBox> Transform(this BoundingBox boundingBox, string epsg) {
    ...
    var min = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://epsg.io/trans?x=435951&y=5549182&s_srs=25832&t_srs=3857");
    var max =  _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://epsg.io/trans?x=435911&y=5549122&s_srs=25832&t_srs=3857");
    await Task.WhenAll(min, max);
    ...
}
```

```cs
priorityBb = bb.Transform("epsg:3857").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But it makes my UI hang.

What is wrong with my code? Many thank for your comment.

Comment: Why would you correctly use `await` inside the function and then [throw it all away](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) when calling the function?

Comment: @GSerg he's still able to get the `min.Result` after the TaskWhenAll

Comment: This `priorityBb = bb.Transform("epsg:3857").GetAwaiter().GetResult();` doesn't look good. The `GetResult();` blocks the current thread. Use `priorityBb = await bb.Transform("epsg:3857");`.. And you need to collect the results somewhere to return them from transform.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen How do you know it's already *after* the `Task.WhenAll`?

Comment: Because the `Task.WhenAll` will continue when all tasks are completed.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen But `Transform` will return the incomplete async task to the caller before `Task.WhenAll` returns. Which is why it is able to [deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Because he doesn't await the `Transform()`, but he directly tries to get the result there. `GetAwaiter().GetResult();`  <-- this will block and wait until the results are retreived.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I see. You understood my ["throw it all away"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343956/asynchronous-task-makes-program-hang#comment108520534_61343956) as a reference to throwing away the result of the function call. No, I was talking about throwing away the async machinery and benefits.

Comment: @GSerg Whoops, I see your point. ;-) "Let's make async, sync again..."

Comment: @GSerg ironically clicking on [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) causes my browser to hang for a while. Probably too many synchronous scripts are running on the loading of the page. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must await the `Transform` method, because the task returned is probably not completed yet instead of `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. You'll probably never need to use these methods. `GetResult()` will block the current thread while the task is not completed.

This is a rough sketch, I have too little information about your structure:

```
public class MyResults
{
    public string Min {get;set;}
    public string Max {get;set;}
}

public static async Task<MyResults> Transform(this BoundingBox boundingBox, string epsg) {
    ...
    var minTask = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://epsg.io/trans?x=435951&y=5549182&s_srs=25832&t_srs=3857");
    var maxTask =  _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://epsg.io/trans?x=435911&y=5549122&s_srs=25832&t_srs=3857");

    await Task.WhenAll(minTask, maxTask);

    // you can access the Results now, because all tasks are completed.
    return new MyResults { Min = minTask.Result, Max = minTask.Result };
}


public static async Task GetMyData()
{
    var myResults = await bb.Transform(".....");
    //              ^^^^^

    Console.WriteLine(myResults.Min);
    Console.WriteLine(myResults.Max);
}
```

---

If the caller isn't supporting async, you could try something like: (haven't tested it so, you'll have to check it)

The `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` is only needed when you are dealing with (for example) a UI thread.

```
public static void GetMyData()
{
    // You are not able to await it here. Fire and "forget"

    Task.Run<MyResults>(() =>
    {
        // Not executed on the UI thread
        return bb.Transform(".....");

    })
    .ContinueWith(transformTask =>
    {
        // back on the UI thread.....
        var myResults = transformTask.Result;

        Console.WriteLine(myResults.Min);
        Console.WriteLine(myResults.Max);

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: thank you very much about your comment. i call `await bb.Transform(".....");` in a execute command in`ViewModel` this `ViewModel` extends from `Screen` Class of `Caliburn.Micro` library

Comment: so if the caller method of `await bb.Transform(".....");` can not set async, how can i deal with it

Answer (score 2):

```
priorityBb = bb.Transform("epsg:3857").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This line is blocking your UI thread, because of call to `GetResult`. Earlier you used `async`/`await` correctly, but in this line you are mixing async code with blocking code. You should use same approach as in `Transform` method and `await` the result instead of blocking using `GetResult`

To fix this simply change that line to

```
priorityBb = await bb.Transform("epsg:3857");
```

Using `GetResult` like that can lead to deadlocks and in most situations is not a good idea. Whenever you can just stick to `async`/`await`.

If you can't make your caller `async` then your call can't be `async`. `async`/`await` is probably best approach here but if for some reason you can't use it you can wait for response and handle it on another thread using [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8)